# Solve a first order differential equation by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a given differential equation
$$xy'+2y\log y -4x^2y = 0;$$ $$ y(1)=1 $$

I want to use the substitution $v=\log y$. Which implies that $$v'=\frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{y} y'$$Hence: $$y'=yv'$$

That being said, solving the equation I try as follows:

$$xyv'+2yv-4x^2y = 0 $$ 
$$xv'+2v = 4x^2 $$
$$v'+\frac{2}{x}v= 4x $$
$$v'=4x-\frac{2}{x}v $$

How can I use seperation of variables here? Or how can I solve this thing ?

thanks

Comment: It is a liner equation, you do not separate the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reduced your equation to the so called [Bernoulli differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). Using notation from wikipedia just set
$$
P(x)=\frac{2}{x}\qquad Q(x)=4x\qquad n=0
$$

Comment: ah thanks. I remember that ;-)

Comment: You are weell come

Comment: @Norbert Why not [Riccati equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) with $q_2(x)=0$?

Comment: @Artem Because Riccati equation is not allways solvable